# Can't override margin-right styling

Tags: css, overriding

I'm modding an image slider and can not figure out how to override the 10px right margin. You'll see the gap on the left edge of slide 2. Thanks for any help.

http://robtaylor.frmboy.com/

Jason

Comment: i didn't find any gap in MOZILLA 4.0 ?? will u make a screenshot; also mention the browser with version in which u r facing the problem

Comment: @diEcho, it's when you click number 2

Comment: Can you please post the original pertinent code? Without it, this question will no longer useful once you fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css file line 8:

```
.jcarousel-skin-default .jcarousel-item-horizontal {margin-left: 0;margin-right: 10px;}
```

Just remove margin-right rule or set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add the following css in your page:

```
.jcarousel-skin-default .jcarousel-item-horizontal {margin-right:0;}
```

I tried it and it works!

Comment: Ya, that works in Firebug, but when I add it to my CSS, it doesn't get applied. I must have a conflict in my stylesheet.